# Recursive function to determine if number is even or odd by subtracting two from n until n = 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, recursion

Zero is even.

One is odd.

For any other number N, its evenness is the same as N - 2.

Define a recursive function isEven corresponding to this description. The function should accept a single parameter (a positive, whole number) and return a Boolean.

Here is my implementation of isEven:

```
let isEven = function(n){
    even = 0;
    odd = 1;
    if(n == even){
      return true;
    }
    else if (n == odd) {
      return false;
    }
    else{
      n -= 2;
      console.log(n); //Used to see value of n through each call
      isEven(n);
    }
  };
```

When I call this function, it returns `undefined`

```
  document.write(isEven(50)); //prints `undefined`
```

The output from `console.log(n)` is the following:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
48
46
...
0
```

I am not sure why `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is the first output, but after that `n` is hitting `0`, so why is

```
if(n == even){
          return true;
        }?
```

not executing?

Comment: Your variables `odd` and `even` are globals. You use uneccesary mutation where instead you could call `isEven(n - 2)` and you throw away the result of the recursion which leaves the result `undefined` when a value isn't returned in a function. Why do you use `return true` and not just `true`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result from the recursive call.

```js
let isEven = function(n){
    const          // declare local variables/constants
        even = 0,
        odd = 1;
    if(n == even){
      return true;
    }
    else if (n == odd) {
      return false;
    }
    else{
      //n -= 2; no need to reassign a value for a single use
      return isEven(n - 2); // return here
    }
  };

console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(21));
```

A better style without `else` parts, because this is not necessary if returned before.

- use values directly, if used only once,
- use strict comparison ([Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)), because not strict can led to wrong assumptions
- take a calculation for the parameter directly without reassign a value to the variable which is not used anymore

```js
let isEven = function(n){
        if (n === 0) return true;
        if (n === 1) return false;
        return isEven(n - 2);
    };

console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(21));
```

Answer (score 2):

But don't miss out on the opportunity to learn about [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)!

```js
const isEven = (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? true
    : isOdd (n - 1)

const isOdd = (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? false
    : isEven (n - 1)
    
console .log
  ( isEven (0)  // true
  , isEven (1)  // false
  , isEven (2)  // true
  , isEven (3)  // false
  , isEven (99) // false
  )
  
console .log
  ( isOdd (0)  // false
  , isOdd (1)  // true
  , isOdd (2)  // false
  , isOdd (3)  // true
  , isOdd (99) // true
  )
```

Comment: if you want to get even more clever, change isOdd to `const isOdd = (n) => !isEven(n)`